# Symfony 5. Too few arguments to function Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::renderBlock()

Tags: symfony5

В Symfony 5 (да и вообще в Symfony) полный новичок. Помогите, пожалуйста, отловить ошибку. Уже неделю бьюсь...

Контроллер:

```
    /* /src/Controller/UserAdminController.php */
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Controller;
    
    use App\Entity\Users;
    use App\Form\UsersEditAdminType;
    //use http\Env\Request;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    
    class UsersAdminController extends AbstractController
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/admin/users", name="admin_users")
         */
        public function users_list()
        {
            return $this->render('users_admin/index.html.twig', [
                'controller_name' => 'UsersAdminController',
            ]);
        }
    
        /**
         * @Route("/admin/users/add", name="admin_users_add")
         */
        public function users_add(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $manager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
        {
            $users = new Users();
            $form = $this->createForm(UsersEditAdminType::class, $users);
            $form->handleRequest($request);
    
            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
                $user->setPassword($password);
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($users);
                $em->flush();
    
                return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_users');
            }
            return $this->render('users_edit_admin/index.html.twig', [
                'controller_name' => 'UsersAdminController',
            ]);
        }
    
        /**
         * @Route("/admin/users/edit/{user_id}", name="admin_users_edit")
         */
        public function users_edit()
        {
            return $this->render('users_edit_admin/index.html.twig', [
                'controller_name' => 'UsersAdminController',
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Сущность:

```
    /* /src/Entity/Users.php */
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Entity;
    
    use App\Repository\UsersRepository;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UsersRepository::class)
     */
    class Users implements UserInterface
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $id;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $username;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $password;
    
        private $passwordPlain;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
         */
        private $usergroup = [];
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
         */
        private $user_status;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $email;
    
        public function getId(): ?int
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
    
        public function getUsername(): ?string
        {
            return $this->username;
        }
    
        public function setUsername(string $username): self
        {
            $this->username = $username;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getPassword(): ?string
        {
            return $this->password;
        }
    
        public function setPassword(string $password): self
        {
            $this->password = $password;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getPasswordPlain(): ?string
        {
            return $this->passwordPlain;
        }
    
        public function setPasswordPlain(string $passwordPlain): self
        {
            $this->passwordPlain = $passwordPlain;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getUsergroup(): ?array
        {
            return $this->usergroup;
        }
    
        public function setUsergroup(?array $usergroup): self
        {
            $this->usergroup = $usergroup;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getUserStatus(): ?int
        {
            return $this->user_status;
        }
    
        public function setUserStatus(?int $user_status): self
        {
            $this->user_status = $user_status;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getRoles()
        {
            // TODO: Implement getRoles() method.
        }
    
        public function getSalt()
        {
            // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
        }
    
        public function eraseCredentials()
        {
            $this->passwordPlain = null;
        }
    
        public function getEmail(): ?string
        {
            return $this->email;
        }
    
        public function setEmail(string $email): self
        {
            $this->email = $email;
    
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

Форма:

```
    /* /src/Form/UserEditAdminType.php */
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Form;
    
    use App\Entity\Users;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
    
    class UsersEditAdminType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('username')
                ->add('passwordPlain', RepeatedType::class, [
                    'type' => PasswordType::class
                ])
                ->add('usergroup', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'choices' => array(
                        'Супер Администратор' => 1,
                        'Администратор' => 2,
                        'Пользователь' => 3,
                    ),
                ))
                ->add('email', EmailType::class)
                ->add('user_status')
            ;
    
    /*        $builder->get('usergroup')
                ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                    function ($usergroupArray) {
                        // transform the array to a string
                        return count($usergroupArray)? $usergroupArray[0]: null;
                    },
                    function ($usergroupString) {
                        // transform the string back to an array
                        return [$usergroupString];
                    }
                )); */
        }
    
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults([
                'data_class' => Users::class,
            ]);
    //        $resolver->setDefaults([]);
        }
    }
```

Шаблон:

```
    /* /templates/user_edit_admin/index.html.twig */
    {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
    
    {% block title %}Управление пользователями{% endblock %}
    
    {% block body %}
        <style>
            .example-wrapper { margin: 1em auto; max-width: 800px; width: 95%; font: 18px/1.5 sans-serif; }
            .example-wrapper code { background: #F5F5F5; padding: 2px 6px; }
        </style>
    
        <div class="example-wrapper">
            <h1>Управление пользователями</h1>
            {{ form_start() }}
            {{ form_widget() }}
            <button type="submit">Сохранить</button>
            {{ form_end() }}
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Таблица в БД (используется Postgres):

```
    CREATE TABLE public."user" (
        id integer NOT NULL,
        email character varying(255) NOT NULL,
        password character varying(255) NOT NULL,
        usergroup integer NOT NULL,
        user_status integer NOT NULL,
        roles json NOT NULL,
        confirmation_code character varying(20) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
        is_confirmed boolean NOT NULL
    );
```

Встроенный в Symfony дебаггер показывает ошибку "Too few arguments to function Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::renderBlock(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/iv/var/cache/dev/twig/b4/b4b4a90f30f2f219c62c85d967bfb0992520ed5566daf4c59152d9027c9fb47a.php on line 97 and at least 2 expected", подсвечивая в файле UsersAdminController.php вторую строку следующего кода:

```
    return $this->render('users_edit_admin/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'UsersAdminController',
    ]);
```

С Symfony только знакомлюсь, нигде в интернете не могу найти что я делаю не так. Помогите, пожалуйста...

Answer (score 0):

В Ютубе есть канал хороший, там мужик все понятно разбирает на примере Symfony 5
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSGq8pEfV1U2GQlV51AA5iA
Может будет полезно
Вопрос по поводу кода, для чего вы возвращаете PasswordPlain? И в сеттер нужно передавать password, а не passwordPlain.

User:

```
public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    public function setPlainPassword($password)
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $password;
    }
```

Контроллер

```
/**
     * @Route("/admin/create", name="admin_create")
     * @param Request $request
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
     * @return Response
     */
    public function createUsers(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {           
           
        $user= new Users();
        $form = $this->createForm(UsersType::class, $user);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
            $user->setPassword($password);
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

           return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_users');
        }

        $forRender = parent::renderDefault();
        $forRender['title'] = 'Форма создания пользователя';
        $forRender['form'] = $form->createView();
        return $this->render('admin/users/form.html.twig',$forRender);

    }
```

Форма

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', TextType::class, array(
                'label'=>'Введите ФИО'
            ))               
            ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
                'type'=>PasswordType::class,
                    'first_options'=>array(
                        'label'=>'Пароль',
                    ),
                    'second_options'=>array(
                        'label'=>'Повтор пароля',
                    )
            ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
                'label'=>'Сохранить'
            ));
    }
```

Comment: plainPassword нужен, чтобы его потом закодировать (забыл в контроллер добавить после проверки получения формы                     $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
                    $user->setPassword($password); ), сейчас добавил

Comment: У меня без его возвращения все работает